# Set controls on readOnly and not disabled CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have the problem that people want another text color for disabled fields in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. Now the problem is, that you cannot change the text color for disabled fields in IE < 10. For the attribute readOnly, it works.

Has someone a good idea, to remove "disabled" attribute of controls and replace it with "readonly" in a nice way without big and manual scripts?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Your request is an unsupported customization, this means you can't achieve this result using the `Xrm` Object Model.

You can always use standard `JavaScript` to manipulate the `DOM` and modify the disabled fields, your code can also check the browser version to make the right changes depending on IE version.

You will need to pay attention if your code still works when you install a new rollup (if you are On-Premise) or when CRM Online gets an update.

Comment: Yes I know that it's unsupported but theres no other way for the users. I must find a solution..

Comment: @Patrik as Guido says, using javascript to change the DOM is the only way to perform this request.  It is "unsupported" (ie Microsoft might make a change that breaks your code at some point in the future), but that is the trade off you make for that type of customization.  Maybe you should just convince the "people" to change their monitor color contrasts?